# Как узнать прозрачность пикселя?

Tags: веб-программирование, gd, php

Мне нужно на пхп узнать степень прозрачности пикселя по его координатам. Функция `ImageColorAt()` даёт только цветовые составляющие без прозрачности. Как средствами PHP узнать узнать насколько прозрачен пиксель? Типа так:

```
<?  
function gettransparent( int image, int x, int y) {  
// какие-то действия  
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если правильно понял ваш вопрос:

```
$rgba = imagecolorat($image, $x, $y);
$alpha = ($rgba & 0x7F000000) >> 24;
```

Значение $alpha, равное 127 соответствует полной прозрачности, а 0 - полной непрозрачности.